# Coding A Product Key

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, security

Ok this is a question about a concept of coding. I have seen many questions on how to implement a product key and I know how to do that, this question is related to the what, than the how.

Ok here is a backstory on what I am doing and then my question. My app Ultimate Diagnostic Suite, is about ready to roll out for testing. I am wanting to implement a product key (I know how to do this). I am torn between on how to do this.

Product Key: 7FD8-S89D-8746G-HUSJ

Product Key: example@example.com

I know how to do a regular product key, however with the first option, I have a random number generator that can generate the keys for me, then I can add them to a db and check the product key, this is fairly simple to do. The only problem I would have is, if 1 million people downloads the application, then that is 1 million product keys. That would take up more space than the app.

However, if I use the email form of a product key, and a person downloads the application, then it would be digitally signed, and would omit that 1 million line product key file. My question is this:

If I use the email form (digital signing), How would I weed out the spam. Also I know I will have wire up some events for the Authorization. I just need a starting point. This is for the ending after the @ symbol, For example:

You would have two textboxes, one textbox will be the `txtUser.Text` and the other to compare to the text file of email endings will be `txtEmailEndings.Text` so in short if an email has the ending of:

```
*@163.com 
*@aichyna.com 
*@berahe.info 



if (txtEmailEndings.Text == dbNotAllowed.Text)
{
  messagebox.Show("Please use a valid email, i.e, Gmail, Outlook, AOL");
}
else if (txtEmailEndings != dbNotAllowed.Text)
{
  // do something to allow access to full program
}
```

with the concept of I would have a list of known email endings that are a High Risk of spam bots. I would think this would cut down on the spam bots, however any email can be made for spam bots.

The only other option I would have is a flat fee, which would go back to the `Flat Fee = Product Key`. With a never ending lines of Product Keys. I do not want to have just one product key for the whole reason, that it can be exploited.

This is not in any particular application such as WinForms or WPF, the concept can be used for both. That is why the tags are listed.

Any questions or comments would be greatly helpful. I am using the concept as digitally signed, the way Microsoft migrated from Product Keys to Digital Signatures.

Comment: * If you add the "product key file" to the application. How do you protect it from the users?
* Why not to use a web-database, where you can query for a valid product key? Maybe the data needs some expiration date?
* Why not to implement a email validation service like "click to confirm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a json file as license file you send when the user purchases the application which contains a RSA signature inside. Your application would have the public key part of the RSA key and it will use to verify the signature of the license and your server will have the secret key used to sign the license files.

The system is decentralized and will be prone to users leaking license files but you could send a machine identifier to your web api when checking for updates and if you detect a lot of distinct machines sharing the same license guid then you mark the license as inactive.

Store the public key part of the RSA key as base64 so it would be harder to find and replace with a hex editor. Additionally you might want to obfuscate your binaries.

Look at this project: https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing/blob/develop/README.md

You can protect against spam emails with Recaptcha and email verification.

You can also give out random product keys which are converted by your api into a signed license file. These keys have limited activations (stored on the server side) and are tied to a machine identifier.

Comment: ok those are good options. The whole thing I am trying to do is, the UDS Application is primarily for me, I am a computer Technician with my own business. So I custom built the whole application instead of using several different applications and stuff like that, I used every WMI possible and other components. Thing is I have not seen any other application like this. So there is a Free version and a paid version. Unless a Big Wig wants to buy it out right. Either way Security is priority, and if a Big Company wants it that is less of a headache on my part.